# Why is theme not applying to custom email?

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

A custom email I am sending is sending with the Luma theme, despite my website having a custom theme applied (which works for checkout emails, yet not for my custom mails).

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

```
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
        ->setTemplateModel('Magento\Email\Model\Template')
        ->setTemplateOptions([
            'area' =>  \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
        ])
        ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $data])
        ->setFrom($sender)
        ->addTo($to)
        ->getTransport();

    $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: from where you sending custom email fronted or backed

Comment: Frontend, frontend area on email template and specifying frontend on email builder

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, my code was using the default store and I had used the code from an example just to find the most clean way of sending a transactional email... the email renderer loads the theme from the store id provided, default is 0 and my store with the theme is 1.

My theme is not applied globally because of a bug, so people with it set to global making this mistake may not see any issues.